# Model Suggestion for Keras Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, regression

I am trying to solve a regression with Keras but MSE is huge, I mean like 29346217.6819

I am really new, so do you have any suggestions to make the model give reasonable mse? I am not sure even my data is OK or problematic but those are actual sales data.

Data (about to 3000 lines. I use 2000 for training and 1000 for testing)
Full data is [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EQMJNv)

```
ProductNo,Day,Month,CartonSales
1,6,02,2374
1,3,02,2374
1,6,04,2374
1,6,04,2374
1,3,06,2374
1,6,09,2374
1,1,09,2374
1,6,09,2374
1,6,10,2374
```

Code

```py
from keras import optimizers
from keras.callbacks import Callback
from numpy import array
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from matplotlib import pyplot
import pandas as pds
# prepare sequence


class TestCallback(Callback):
    def __init__(self, test_data):
        self.test_data = test_data

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        x, y = self.test_data
        loss, acc = self.model.evaluate(x, y, verbose=0)
        print('\nTesting loss: {}, acc: {}\n'.format(loss, acc))

dataframe = pds.read_csv('pmidata.csv', usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3])
dataframe = dataframe.sample(frac=1)

dataframeX_train = dataframe.iloc[0:2000][['ProductNo', 'Day', 'Month']]
dataframeY_train = dataframe.iloc[0:2000][['CartonSales']]

dataframeX_test = dataframe.iloc[2001:3001][['ProductNo', 'Day', 'Month']]
dataframeY_test = dataframe.iloc[2001:3001][['CartonSales']]

# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(3, input_dim=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse'])
#sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
#model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['mse'])
# train model
#history = model.fit(dataframe, dataframe, epochs=500, batch_size=len(X), verbose=2)
history = model.fit(dataframeX_train, dataframeY_train, epochs=100, batch_size=4, verbose=2, callbacks=[TestCallback((dataframeX_test, dataframeY_test))])
# plot metrics
pyplot.plot(history.history['mean_squared_error'])
pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as i can tell from your code above, your y values are CartonSales. Sales can have large values and large range and that's probably why you get such a high error. You could use mean_squared_logarithmic_error instead of mean square error but i would suggest to do the following.

Continue using mean square error.
log transform you y values and later exp transform you predictions

```python
import numpy as np
dataframeY_train = np.log(dataframeY_train)
dataframeY_test = np.log(dataframeY_test )
....
predictions=model.predict(dataframeX_test)[:,0]
predictions = np.exp(predictions)
```

Comment: Thank you, log worked like magic! My mse is now 0.4 but 

Testing loss: 0.44639948797225953, acc: 0.44639948797225953
accuracy is still too low. Do you think I am testing my perfomance correctly?

Comment: i would suggest an increase to num of neuron from 3 to above 100
like model.add(Dense(100, input_dim=3, activation='relu')),
depending of your hardware capabilities

Comment: Thank you so much again, I changed the code accordingly your suggestion. Now results are
Testing loss: 0.47014914894104004, acc: 0.47014914894104004

Does 0.47 acc mean %47?

Comment: accuracy is meaningful in classification problems, this is a regression problem, you should pay attention to you mse

Comment: So how can I test my modal manually sir? I mean supplying hard coded data and getting predicted value. Thank you so much again for your help